# Using inotools to upload to Arduino

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My robot project uses a headless Ubuntu install for ROS, with a networked Ubuntu VM for doing GUI ROS tasks, and I'd like to be able to edit and upload Arduino firmware from SSH directly.

I managed to get ino installed to do Arduino compiling but it stalls repeatedly because it can't find ros.h. Has anyone successfully uploaded rosserial firmware with ino or any other command line utility? I've coped the ros_libs folder into the ino workspace lib folder but that doesn't help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204513/using-inotools-to-upload-to-arduino/) by [Wes G](https://answers.ros.org/users/8681/wes-g/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2015-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosserial recently added cmake capabilities to allow you to upload the firmware using catkin.  Check out this [example](https://github.com/mikepurvis/hello_arduino) .

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2015-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wes G](https://answers.ros.org/users/8681/wes-g/) on 2015-03-09**:
That's great, I'll have to look into that more.

**Comment by [Wes G](https://answers.ros.org/users/8681/wes-g/) on 2015-03-10**:
Marking this question the answer, because it directed me to the catkin wormhole. After a day though, it's working!